# ggplot geom_bar is plotting counts rather than values, even with stat="identity" setting enabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-ggplot

I am using ggplot in python and just trying to make a basic bar chart. For reasons I don't understand, the bar heights are corresponding to counts of variable names, rather than the actual variables.

Simple example

```
pattern = pd.Series(['standard', 'woolly', 'brown', 'spotted', 'red', 'wheat', 'grey'], dtype = 'category')
population = pd.Series([12, 2, 7, 3, 2, 4,5])
patternCount = pd.DataFrame({'color':pattern, 'population':population})

ggplot(aes(x = 'attribute', y = 'population'), data = animalCounts) +\
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Gives me a bar chart that looks like this.
[image: Barplot that shows counts rather than values]

I know these are counts, rather than just the number one, since if I have duplicate of any of these names, that variable shows as "2".

I presume I am making some really simple mistake here.  Thanks for any help.

Edit: As per Ron Norris's request, here is the same figure, but scaled to 12, rather than 1.

[image: as above but scaled differently]

Comment: ...and all of the populations are > 1 (which is the maximum on the y-scale). Can you extend the y-scale?

Comment: I re-scaled as @Ron Norris requested. One can now see that the values all actually only go up to 1.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently I need to specify

```
weight = 'population'
```

rather than

```
y = 'population
```

Thus the correct code is

```
p = ggplot(aes(x = 'color', weight = 'population'),data = patternCount) +\
geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

And gives a figure that looks like
[image: bar chart that behaves correctly]

Comment: Thank you so much! it's really strange why ggplot in python has this behavior though.